# Cannot extract some records from text file

Tags: c++, file, text-files, extract, dev-c++

I need to extract and display records from a text files containing data, every time some conditions are met. The problem is that some records are omitted when I extract them from text file. Any help will be appreciated. My code is below, written in Dev-C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char manufacturer[16], model[16], year[10];
  int miles,car_cost;
  char response, line[256];
  string field1, field2, field3;

  int   MilesText ,car_costText;
  ofstream OS ("usedcars.txt", ios::out);
  cout<<"for each car please enter :"<<endl;

  do
  {
    ofstream OS ("usedcars.txt", ios::app);

    cout<<"The manufacturer: ";
    cin.getline(manufacturer, 16);
    cout<<"The model: ";
    cin.getline(model, 16);
    cout<<"The year: ";
    cin.getline(year, 8);
    cout<<"The miles: ";
    cin>>miles;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"The cost of car $: ";
    cin>>car_cost;

    OS<<  manufacturer << setw(9) <<  model << setw(8) << year << setw(11) << miles << setw(8) << car_cost<<endl;
    cout<<"Do you want to continue?";
    cin>>response;
    cin.ignore();
  }
    while (response!='n');  
    OS.close();
    cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"the record found"<<endl;
    ifstream IS ("usedcars.txt", ios::in);
    while(!IS.eof())
    {   
      IS>>field1>>field2>>field3>>MilesText>>car_costText;
      if(MilesText<50000 && car_costText<9000)  //if the miles is less than 50000 and        the cost  is less than 9000 therefore...

     while(IS)
      {
       IS.getline(line, 256);
       if(IS)
       cout<<line<<endl;  //display the record from text file
     }
 }
IS.close();
getch();
return 0;  
}
```

**********************the output********************************************

```
for each car please enter :
The manufacturer: Mitsubishi
The model: Lancer
The year: 2001
The miles: 12300
The cost of car $: 10780
Do you want to continue?y
The manufacturer: Ford
The model: Escape
The year: 2004
The miles: 150000
The cost of car $: 6200
Do you want to continue?y
The manufacturer: Audi
The model: A4
The year: 1999
The miles: 79000
The cost of car $: 11000
Do you want to continue?n
```

---

the record found

*************************in text file**************************************

```
Mitsubishi   Lancer    2001      12300   10780
Ford   Escape    2004     150000    6200
Audi       A4    1999      79000   11000
Volvo      S80    1998      14000    7900
```

Comment: while(IS)
      {
       IS.getline(line, 256);
       if(IS) i dont understand the logic. can u clarify?

Comment: And why cant you use a struct or class?

Comment: As long as we still have data in the file, extract the line.

Comment: We have not covered struct or class yet.

Comment: so only the first record is read? did you check the .txt file to see if all the records are properly written?

Comment: actually, either the first one, or the last record is not read, even though they all appear in the text file.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions for your problem (the part reading the input file), at least if I understood what you want to do correctly. For me it prints all cars with a mileage<50000 and a price below 9000 out of the input file.

```
#include <sstream>
// rest of your code...

ifstream IS ("usedcars.txt", ios::in);
string lineTextfile;

while(IS)
{   
    getline(IS, lineTextfile); // read one line of input file

    istringstream parseLine(lineTextfile);

    parseLine>>field1>>field2>>field3>>MilesText>>car_costText; // parse individual elements of that line

    if(MilesText<50000 && car_costText<9000)  //if the miles is less than 50000 and        the cost  is less than 9000 therefore...
    {
        cout<<lineTextfile<<endl;  //display the record from text file
    }
}

IS.close();
```

The reading of the data from the filestream *and* a stringstream is somewhat redundant, but it is close to the example you started with.

---

If you like to use a `struct` you could use this code to overload stream operators like this:

```
struct Car
{
    Car() : year(0), mileage(0), price(0) {};
    string manufacturer;
    string model;
    unsigned int year;
    unsigned int mileage;
    unsigned int price;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Car& car)
{
    is >> car.manufacturer >> car.model >>  car.year >>  car.mileage >>  car.price;
    return is;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Car& car)
{
    os << car.manufacturer << " " << car.model << " " <<  car.year << " " <<  car.mileage << " " <<  car.price;
    return os;
}

bool IsFairPricedCar(const Car& car)
{
    return car.price < 9000 && car.mileage < 50000;
}
```

With that `struct` definition the following is possible:

```
ifstream IS ("usedcars.txt", ios::in);

while (IS)
{
    Car readCar;
    IS >> readCar;
    if(readCar.mileage < 50000 && readCar.price < 9000)
    {
        cout << readCar << endl;
    }
}

IS.close();
```

**Alternative**:

```
ifstream IS2 ("usedcars.txt", ios::in);

copy_if(istream_iterator<Car>(IS2), istream_iterator<Car>(),
    ostream_iterator<Car>(cout, "\n"), IsFairPricedCar);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you read the properties of your car and if they match you print the next line. Another thing you might want to make sure is that the values you write don't contain spaces. When writing you values you probably should make sure that there is at least one space between values.

I spotted that you use `eof()` for the condition in the loop: this is definitely wrong and you want to use just the implicit conversion to `bool`. The only use of `eof()` is to suppress error reports when reading failed because you reached the end of the file.